# find and extract string from long list with repeating pattern

Tags: python, regex, parsing, sed

I have two lists of text which I would like to extract certain information.

The first line (first few terms) looks like

```
line = "{"af":"16.63","al":"11.58",..."
```

I would like to extract only the letters between "" into a list if possible. e.g. `["af","al"...]`.

The second line is very long and contains a sequence which looks like

```
line = "...,"name":"Papua New Guinea"},..."
```

I just want the string after `"name":"<country>"` to be in another list if possible. e.g. `[...,"Papua New Guinea",...]`. The same pattern appears again and and again `"name":"<country>"}`, I would just like the countries.

These both could be piped to two lists in different files using SED perhaps. I just need to get rid of all of the surrounding "fluff".

I've tried a combination of regex but it doesn't work. I can't get the syntax correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `line` string is invalid; you cannot embed `"` in a string delimited by `"`; not unquoted, at least.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you have JSON data; use the `json` module to turn that into Python structures.

Comment: Yes it is JSON data. I'll look into it Martijn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at JSON data; use the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse this into Python structures. The rest of your tasks are then easy:

```
first_structure = json.loads(line)
print first_structure.keys()

second_structure = json.loads(countries_text)
print [d['name'] for d in second_structure]
```

Comment: So what if this is in a file. e.g. the only line in the file is: jQuery.fn.vectorMap('addMap', 'world_en', {"width":950,"height":550,"pathes":{"id":{"path":... rest of data

Comment: @Griff: then you have *JavaScript*. JSON is a subset of JavaScript, so if you can extract the parts between the first `{` and the last `}` in that line (using `str.partition()` and `str.rpartition()` or `str.split()` and `str.rsplit()` with a limit of 1 split) then you can **usually** parse the result as JSON.

Comment: I can't partition is as it is nested by the looks of it. http://pastebin.com/Rct5yVie

Comment: @Griff: That is *one* big structure; I managed to load it with `countries = json.loads(data.partition(' = ')[2])`, so splitting on the equals sign; `countries['pathes'].keys()` gives me all the country codes, `[d['name'] for d in countries['pathes'].values()]` all the country names.

Comment: why are you partitioning by '=', the data starts at {. I simply had countries = to show you what I was using in my python script. Should i have countries = json.loads("id"...)?

Comment: @Griff: By partitioning at `' = '` the string is split in two at that point, the last element being the complete JavaScript value from `{` to `}`.

Comment: @Griff: If that wasn't the input string from which you are trying to extract the data, then show me that that string instead.

Comment: @Griff: Right, split on the comma twice, remove whitespace and the last two characters: `inputstring.split(',', 2)[-1].strip(' );')` and you are done.